# solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have given the following differential equation:

$x'= - y$ and $y' = x$

How can I solve them?

Thanks for helping!
Greetings

Comment: It's in fact a differential system. You can differentiate in both sides of the first equation, use the second to get an equation involving only $x$.

Comment: Isn't there a rather obvious pair of trigonometric functions that might satisfy these equations (assuming that the prime indicates differentiation with respect to some third variable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you differentiate $y'$, you have:
$$y'' = -y$$
Which has the solutions:
$$y=C_1 \cos(t) + C_2 \sin(t),$$

Answer (score 1):

Introduce the complex dependent variable $z=x+iy,$ then your ode is $$z'=iz,$$ where $'$ is again the differentiation w.r.t. the independent variable $t$.
The characteristic polinomial is $P(\lambda)=\lambda-i,$ so the general solution is $$z(t)=\alpha.e^{it},$$ for an arbitrary $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$.

**P.S.** : By the way your original system is the Hamilton equation for the harmonic oscillator $$H(x,y)=\tfrac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle X(t)= \binom{x(t)}{y(t)}$ so

$$ X' = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1  \\
1 & 0  \\
\end{array} \right)X .$$

This has solution $$ X(t)=  \exp\biggr(  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -t  \\
t & 0  \\
\end{array} \right) \biggr) X(0)=   \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & e^{-t}  \\
e^t & 0  \\
\end{array} \right)\binom{x(0)}{y(0)}$$

so $$ x(t) = y(0) e^{-t}  \ \ \text{ and } \ \   y(t) = x(0) e^{t} . $$

Comment: your solution is not correct. In particular, the matrix exponent cannot be calculated as shown.